# How to call variables in a for loop as both the variable name and the variable value

Tags: linux, bash, variables, for-loop

Im relatively new to scripting in Linux (more used to using R) but I am trrying to excecute a script where I set a number of variables as file paths which I can then subsequently call in a for loop So I can call both the variable name and the variable values separately across the script.

For example I will call the variable value (as in the file path) for the arguments of the command, but for the output of the command I will call the variable name to write the output. I have tried to achieve this using the curly brackets below. Will this work???

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

```
#Generate variables with path directories
C1=/path/file1
C2=/path/file2
C3=/path/file3
C4=/path/file4
L1=/path/file1
L2=/path/file2
L3=/path/file3

#Loop through each instance of C for each instance of L (to create L*C number of outputs)
for Cid in C1, C2, C3, C4,
do for Lid in L1, L2, L3,
do
commandA -arg1 $${Cid} -arg2 $${Lid} -output /path/file${Cid}${Lid}
done
done
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a job for associative array declared with `declare -A`:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

declare -A arr=(
[C1]=/path/file1
[C2]=/path/file2
[L1]=/path/file1
[L2]=/path/file2
)

for index in "${!arr[@]}"; do
    echo "$index:${arr[$index]}"
done
```

- `${!arr[@]}`: all indexes of the array (`C1`, `C2`, ... )
- `${arr[$index]}`: array element corresponding to the given index (`/path/file1`, ... )

---

If you want to stick to regular variables, you can use [variable indirection](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html):

```
C1=/path/file1
C2=/path/file2
L1=/path/file1
L2=/path/file2

for var in C1 C2 L1 L2; do
    echo "$var:${!var}"
done
```

> `${!parameter}`
>
> If the first character of `parameter` is an exclamation point (`!`), and
>   `parameter` is not a nameref, it introduces a level of variable
>   indirection. Bash uses the value of the variable formed from the rest
>   of `parameter` as the name of the variable; this variable is then
>   expanded and that value is used in the rest of the substitution,
>   rather than the value of `parameter` itself.

Comment: Thanks very much, this helped immensely!

Comment: @kingdj Glad it helped. Please take a look at [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)